# OpenCV error opening RTSP URL

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, rtsp

I'm using VideoCapture method to open IP Camera using RTSP protocol, before it i tried open video from file and it works fine but if i'm open video stream from RTSP protocol i get this error notice from command prompt.

```
[04:23:10.798] FigFileForkOpenMainByCFURL signalled err=2 (errno) (open failed) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia_frameworks/CoreMedia-1562.240/Sources/Platform/Darwin/DarwinFile.c line 437
```

[04:23:10.798] <<<< FigFile >>>> FigFileForkOpenMainByCFURL: opening url "file:///Users/pieter/Desktop/OpenCV/InputVideo/build/Debug/rtsp:/192.168.100.10", path "/Users/pieter/Desktop/OpenCV/InputVideo/build/Debug/rtsp:/192.168.100.10" options 0x00000000 failed errno 2 No such file or directory
VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!

This is how i open IP camera using video capture

```
VideoCapture cap("rtsp://192.168.100.10");
```

I'm using Xcode 6.1 and OpenCV 3.2.0, is there something wrong? thank you in advance

Comment: I think that it's not full url of rtsp steam. I opened streams many times without any trouble, but depending on your camera, you must add something like `rtsp://ip-address/live.sdp`

Comment: is there any RTSP stream on your network ? if it s not, you cant capture anything...